# Liberty on Windows/Linux

Tags: websphere-liberty

I try to deploy a JAVA application on Liberty (I will use <> as place holder)

1. On Windows:
   If I add my application in Eclipe with the help of the Add and Remove.. Ressource, the application runs successfully on Liberty. In `\wlp\usr\servers\<ServerName>\apps` a new file `<MyAppName>.war.xml` is created:

`<dir sourceOnDisk="C:\<MyAppName>\<MyAppName>-source\src\main\webapp" targetInArchive="/"/>`

2. On Windows:
   If I create in `\wlp\usr\servers\<ServerName>\apps` the file `<MyAppName>.war.xml` manually and link it to the `<MyApp>.war` directory:

`<dir sourceOnDisk="C:\Users\<userName>\Desktop\<MyAppName>.war" targetInArchive="/"/>`
the application runs successfully.

3. On Linux:
   I want now to deploy the same war on a Liberty server on linux. The problem is the structure of the directories- it is completely different than in Windows.
   In the appl directory, there are the following subdirectories:
   appl_dropins
   wl_config

Where do I have to put the file `<MyAppName>.war.xml`? And the `server.xml`? Why is so different on Linux?

On Windows the structure was for the `<ServerName>` apps, dropins, logs,resources, tranlog, workarea + the File server.xml

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The directory structure is identical on windows and linux. There isn't an appl directory on any platforms, was that a typo? The .war.xml is used in development mode and doesn't translate across platforms. If you are trying to copy something from one platform to another use the server package tool.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy directly from Eclipse it is pointing to the workspace by default, which is good for development, but not for deployment to other environments.

You have following options:

- change publishing options in Eclipse to publish `war` by unchecking 'Run applications directly from workspace'
- Export application from Eclipse using Export > War file
- or create packaged server - right click on your server select Utilities > Package server and then use 'usr' option.

Packed server option is quite good for moving between environments, as it gathers all - application, server.xml, and any other files you had in the server folder. Then you just unzip archive on your target host and run the server.

As Alasdair said there is no difference in directory structure between Win and Linux, so either you have some different product on Linux, or it was heavily customized by someone or some tool.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fast answer.

I did as you said. I created the war `<MyAppNewName.war>` file, unzip it `<MyAppNewName>` and put it in the dropings directory. When I start the server, I get among other exceptions the following one:
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The server is not configured to handle the resource at location C:\kits\wlp-webProfile7-18.0.0.1\wlp\usr\servers\newTest\dropins\<MyAppNewName>\index.xhtml.

For the App in the orginal question, the file <MyAppName>.war.xml contained

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="C:\Users\userName\Desktop\MyAppName.war" targetInArchive="/"/>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="C:\MyAppName\MyAppName-source\target\classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/> 
</archive>
```

In C:\MyAppName\MyAppName-source\target\classes there are the .class files and the war does not contain them.

So how do I add the .classes to the war?

Comment: Ahh, in that case I was not clear enough. If you exported war file, you just drop it to the dropins folder, and remove any  *.war.xml files from the apps folder, and remove application entry from server.xml. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: thank you for the answer. You can see my comment below- here there is not so much space :)

Comment: How do you build and then create `war`? You should select your project then right click and select `Export > war file`. This should create proper web application archive where you have your web files at root folder and classes in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. If that is not the case then your project is incorrectly setup.